# Sudden increase in pageviews on google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

[image]

As you can see the pages per session almost dupplicated overnight. Doesn't make sense to me so I investigated and GA only tracks one page once. I refresh the website and only one event is sent to GA. I move around and only 1 event per page is sent.

At the moment on a new page refresh it loads:

- https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (from service worker)
- https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js
- https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
- https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect....
- https://www.google.com/ads/ga-audiences...
- https://www.google.co.jp/ads/ga-audiences...

What do you think it might be?

[image]

Average time on page also decreased... but average session duration increased

[image]

The only thing that happen at that time, were those 2 peaks. Since then things got messed up for some reason. Also the website has been rebuild in at some time after the 2 peaks and I don't see any differences. Maybe the previous tracking thing was not working properly?

Any other explanations?

Code for GA:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
window.gtag = function() {
  window.dataLayer && window.dataLayer.push(arguments)
}
window.gtag('js', new Date())
const trackingId = config.trackingId
window.gtag('config', trackingId, {
  send_page_view: false,
})
loadScript(`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js`)
loadScript(`https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js`)
```

Tracking with:

```
  window.gtag('config', trackingId, {
    'page_title': '...',
    'page_path': '...',
  })
```

Bounce also decreased to around 60%.

Comment: You need to either provide the method of implementation, code that's put on the page or link to the site in question. Otherwise we can't tell by just looking at the graph. That said, what's the bounce rate like? If it is suspiciously low since the change, then you might be double counting somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question.

Comment: The code looks valid, did you have checked the Browser version of that increase? Did you have the enabled the "Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders"?

Comment: I will take a look. Also if I mess up (more aggressive marketing) the pages the bounce rate increases dramatically, so I think it should kind of work ok.